# Change /wp-login.php?action=logout URL for WordPress to /logout

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been googling for 20 mins plus and still couldn't find the answer. I saw [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58453/how-to-change-the-default-logout-link-on-wordpress-admin) but it's about redirecting to a different page to log out but URL remains the same.

I'm looking to change `mysite.com/wp-login.php?action=logout` to `mysite.com/logout`

Is that possible?

Comment: Actually your reference link provided the answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77047/3608

Comment: @Raptor Sorry but I prefer a non-htaccess method since it will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work

```
add_filter('parse_request', 'custom_logout');
function custom_logout($request){
    if  ( $request->query_vars['pagename']=='logout'){ 
        wp_logout();
        wp_set_current_user(0);
    }
}
```

Probably you should create a page with slug 'logout' to avoid 404 page